# PHP FTP : Access Denied

Tags: php, ftp

I was working on with a FTP upload from my php page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
flush();

$ftp_server = "myserver";
$ftp_user_name="myuser";
$ftp_user_pass="mypass";
$remote_file="myfile.txt";
$file="myfile.txt";

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
 ?>
```

It gives me a Warning in browser like

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Access is denied. in /var/www/html/ftpcheck.php on line 17. There was a problem while uploading myfile.txt.
```

I checked the access permissions on the file. But its accessible. Can any one tell me why this happens?

Comment: Can you use a regular FTP application (for example http://filezilla-project.org/) to put the file? It might be a permission on the directory you are uploading to.

Comment: @andyb: i cannot do this manually. I have to do this becoz, i want to ftp upload one file that i receive from a user using php upload. i was testing it

Comment: You should test the FTP upload independently of your code to rule out a problem on the FTP server, for example a permission problem on the directory being uploaded to

Comment: It is not accessible. That's why the error says that access is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this is a permission issue. When you are uploading a file via FTP, you also need to check the directory's permission. When you're saying it's accessible, it doesn't mean it's writable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the result of [the login operation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php):

```
if (ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user_name@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user_name\n";
}
```

You should also try a manual FTP operation from the PHP host to the FTP host to ensure that you can log-on with these credentials and put a file. This will help you establish whether it's your code at fault or the FTP credentials.

Answer (score -1):

```
           <?php 
           class Ftp {
          function upload()
         {
           $ftp_server="50.56.113.39";
           $ftp_user_name="******";
           $ftp_user_pass="***";
           $file = "form.pdf";//tobe uploaded
           $remote_file = "uploads1/test.pdf";

        // set up basic connection
         $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

         // login with username and password
         $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

         // upload a file
        if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file,  FTP_BINARY))
         {
          echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
         //exit;
         } 
         else
           {
            echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
            //exit;
            }
           // close the connection
         ftp_close($conn_id);

          }
            }
          ?>
```